# Can the Angular CLI create a work-space with multiple apps that share one or more libraries within the workspace?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am just about wrapping up a migration from angularJS 1.4 to Angular 7.1 and am currently playing around with the conversion of our custom Webpack builds to the CLI. We have about 10 separate angular apps living together each with a custom Webpack build (they are almost identical). I want to get these projects all using the Angular CLI but ***the problem is that all of these apps utilize another app that is mostly a UI component library with some utility pipes, services, and directives***.

My question is how does the Angular CLI manage this situation, or how do I need to reorganize our project to conform to the Angular CLI style?

I know that in Angular 6 introduced work-spaces and I have tried adding our apps within a work-space but ran into issues creating a shared utility app within that work-space. I am hoping to get some opinions/incites on how to orchestrate this move to the CLI. Let me know if there is any information that I have left out and I will be happy to add more details. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What you looking for is call monorepo. Have a look at `nrwl nx`(https://nx.dev/). `Nx` extends Angular CLI. Angular workspace works just as good the last time I used it as well.

Comment: Angular libraries should work for you. Have a look: https://nitayneeman.com/posts/making-an-addable-angular-package-using-schematics/ and https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-library-in-angular-2-and-publish-to-npm-from-scratch-f2b1272d6266

Comment: You could scale the approach from the second link to your problem. I am using it just for testing my npm package (https://github.com/DanielHabenicht/ngx-propagation-stop) but you could move your shared app into a library just like I am doing it with my packages and build it. Then reuse it in every other app. This can be set up in a monorepo as well as decoupled by publishing to an npm registry.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I was aware of Nx but I was a little confused about what it solved over Angular's new works-spaces. I thought that maybe Angular had simply integrated what Narwhal had done into the CLI. I will dig into all of these resources more. Also I was kind of hoping not to publish the UI library as an npm package because I was worried about having to maintain that as well but I will research more about it.

Comment: Nice thing about `Nx` is that it is aware of your libraries when you are doing development with `ng serve` So if anything changes on your library it builds the libraries that has been changed.

Comment: @penleychan I just watched the Nx demo video and there are some really compelling features that it adds to the CLI...I think I am going to spin up a project with Nx and see how it feels.